# CQ5/Sling - handle POST request

Tags: jsp, post, aem, sling

I'm new to CQ5 and I need to handle HTTP POST request with my component. I have following directory structure

```
/apps/TEST_project/components/myComponent/myComponent.jsp
/apps/TEST_project/components/myComponent/myComponent.POST.jsp
```

and this form in myComponent.jsp

```
<form action="<%resource.getPath();%>myPage.html" method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data">
Name <input type="text" name="name" /><br />
E-mail <input type="text" name="email" /><br />
File <input type="file" name="file" /><br />
    <input type="submit" id="Upload" value="Upload" title="Upload" />
</form>
```

but whenever I submit the form i get just page that tells me this

```
Content modified /content/TEST_project/myPage

Status  
200
Message 
OK
Location    /content/TEST_project/myPage
Parent Location /content/TEST_project
Path    
/content/TEST_project/myPage
Referer http://localhost:4502/content/TEST_project/myPage
ChangeLog   
<pre></pre>
```

instead of the myComponent.POST.jsp script.

Yesterday I spent few hours trying to make this work but without any result... Thank for any help

Comment: why are you adding mypage.html at the end of the form action? the action should be the resource itself. otherwise you are modifying another node that might not me a "myComponent" resource.

Answer (score 4):

By adding `myPage.html` to the end of your action, the action of your form becomes `/content/TEST_project/myPage.html`

Since `/content/TEST_project/myPage` doesn't resolve to a resource, Sling by default will create one at this location (with a `201 Created` status). If you try posting again, it will now resolve against this new node, but since this node doesn't have a resource type, it's now using the default Post servlet to modify this resource.

As others have said, to get the form submission handled by your JSP, you'd need the form action to be `<%= resource.getPath() %>.html` or `<%= currentNode.getPath() %>.html` (The ".html" extension is optional, but just going with the syntax you have above).

This will mean that the form submission will still resolve to a resource type of `/apps/TEST_project/components/myComponent`. From there, your file name of `myComponent.POST.jsp` should work to resolve a POST request and handle the form submission.

Answer (score 1):

Try renaming myComponent.POST.jsp to POST.jsp.  I believe with the way you have it now your myComponent.POST.jsp script will be mapped to a request that looks like ../myPage.POST.html.

Check out Adobe's cheat sheet on how requests are mapped to component scripts:
http://dev.day.com/content/ddc/blog/2008/07/cheatsheet/_jcr_content/images/cheatsheet/front.png

Answer (score 1):

In the form action,change the action as
         **action="<%currentNode.getPath();%>"**

Thanks,
Balaji.